# Casting to arbitrary version of generic class

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Impactable<T> : where T : Spawnable<T>
{
    protected T spawnable = Spawnable<T>.Instance;

    void DoSomethingIndependentOfT(){}
}
```

The reason I have it implemented like this is because Spawnable is a Lazy extendable Singleton. In Impactable, I have of course methods that utilize `spawnable`, but also methods that don't that I'd like to access externally by casting.

```
public sealed class EnemySpawnable : Spawnable<EnemySpawnable>
{
}

public class MyEnemyA : Impactable<EnemySpawnable>
{
}

MyEnemyA enemy = new MyEnemyA();
Impactable x = enemy;
x.DoSomethingIndependentOfT();
```

Is it possible to achieve a cast like this in C# or will I have to re-engineer my code?

Comment: You basically did it already in your sample code. Define a base class `Impactable` that the `Impactable<T>` derives from and put the independent stuff there.

Comment: That kidn of is the obvious solution isn't it xD .. However, I'm looking to learn, in general, if such casting is possible as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not. The type argument constraint on `Impactable` (`where`) prevents it. But the refactoring required is non-breaking and trivial. The solution is to promote the type-independent methods to a base class which does not require specialization, like so:

```
public class Spawnable<T>
{
    public static T Instance;
}

public class Impactable
{
    internal void DoSomethingIndependentOfT() { }
}

public class Impactable<T> : Impactable where T : Spawnable<T>
{
    protected T spawnable = Spawnable<T>.Instance;
}

public sealed class EnemySpawnable : Spawnable<EnemySpawnable>
{
}

public class MyEnemyA : Impactable<EnemySpawnable>
{
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyEnemyA enemy = new MyEnemyA();
        Impactable x = enemy;
        x.DoSomethingIndependentOfT();
    }
}
```

Even if what you intended would be possible (or is made possible in future versions of C#), it's still much cleaner to do it this way, because it self-documents the intent (methods that do not use generics, should not reside in a container scoped to a constrained type).

Comment: That's a brilliant and simple solution and works great with my specific problem in Unity, thanks a lot